# Using Windows Mobile List View in LargeIcon mode

Tags: windows-mobile

How can I use the ListView in Windows Mobile in LargeIcon mode so that I cab Display My Thumbnails in them...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem.  What about setting the [View property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view.aspx) to [View.LargeIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.view.aspx) doesn't work?